Is there a cross platform (Windows/Mac) way to start a service when an app is launched?
I've created a plugin for an app I'm using, which uses said app's API to send commands. The plugin is in two parts - an HTTP server, which listens on a port and sends the commands via the API, and a Stream Deck client plugin, which sends commands to the HTTP server. It has to be in two parts due to the API library being written in C#, whereas the Stream Deck client is written in JS (obviously).
The server portion is designed to run as a background service - that is, on startup, it starts an HTTP server and listens for any commands until it is shut down. However, I don't want it to be running all the time, for obvious reasons, so is there a way on Windows and Mac that I can listen for when the app I want to control is launched, and trigger a service start that way? (I have no access to the source code of the original app.) Bonus points if I can somehow automate the setup of this process! If this isn't possible, does anyone have any alternative suggestions?
